# STS not updating webapp path despite path not present anymore in whole project

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I had a STS Spring MVC project called "simplemvc", it ran fine.
Then, I rewrote *every* occurrence of "simplemvc" to "myproject".

**PROBLEM**: When I right-click on the webapp in "Servers" and choose "Open Home Page", it opens http://localhost:8080/simplemvc/ and even loads correctly.

- I ran `grep -R` to make sure the string "simplemvc" is nowhere.
- I ran `mvn clean`
- I removed all webapps from Servers, deleted all servers, recreated a clean server, added the webapp again, and restarted STS
- If I make a change in a JSP, it is visible immediately. Only the URL stays stubbornly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This path is not configured in the project's source code.

Rather, it is an STS metadata. It can be modified in:

Properties > Web Project Settings > Context root

[image: Web Project Settings - Context root]